# Find the derivative of the function. y = $\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}} $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

This question is really tricky. I am wondering if I am right? [image]

Comment: Is that $\sqrt{7x\sqrt{7x\sqrt{7x}}}$ or $\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x\sqrt{7x}}}$?

Comment: $\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}$

Comment: @Cetshwayo your photo indicates that you're considering $\sqrt{7x\sqrt{7x\sqrt{7x}}}$.

Comment: I made a mistake with my calculation. I will do it again.

Comment: @Cetshwayo the title of your post, the first line of your photo and the remaining of your photo give contradictory information. What is your $y$?

Comment: @Kim Jong Un        y = $\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}} $

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial. You are almost a two-years member, is about time.

Answer (score 4):

Note you can make it slightly less messy by squaring both sides and using implicit differentiation:

$$y^2 = 7x + \sqrt{7x + \sqrt{7x}}$$

$$\implies 2y \dfrac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{\mathrm d 7x}{\mathrm dx} + \dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left({\sqrt{7x + \sqrt{7x}}}\right) $$

When you're done with the RHS, divide both sides by $2y = 2\sqrt{7x + \sqrt{7x + \sqrt{7x}}}$

Comment: Even better, don't stop at one square.  Move $7x$ to the left and then square again.

Comment: @Paul: that is exactly what Frieder does in [his answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1191232/94971).

Answer (score 1):

Build from inside:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{7x}&=\frac{7}{2\sqrt{7x}}\\
\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}\cdot\left(7+\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{7x}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}\cdot\left(7+\frac{7}{2\sqrt{7x}}\right)\\
\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}\cdot\left(7+\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
where you can plug in the expression for $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}$ found in the second to last line to finish the calculation to end up with
$$
y'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}\cdot\left(7+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}\cdot\left(7+\frac{7}{2\sqrt{7x}}\right)\right)
$$
and now it should be a childs play even finding the derivative of $\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}$ if you feel like it.

Comment: This is really great! (+1)

Comment: @Frieder: Thank you, that is great to hear!

Comment: Tried to find something like you did. But I failed.
So I'm very happy to see, that you've found, what I was looking
for. Very nice!
Your idea show's very ellegant, not to loose control over terms
during differetiation process. And that's very powerfull.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}=\frac{7+\frac{7+7/(2\sqrt{7x})}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}=\frac{7+14\sqrt{7x}+28\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}{8\sqrt{7x}\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}$$
I hope it is correct.

Comment: Isn't it always better to turn the roots into fractional exponents?

Comment: No, for (square) roots look better (to me).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}{l}
f(x) = \sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } } \\
{f^2}(x) = 7x + \sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } \\
{f^2}(x) - 7x = \sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } \\
{\left( {{f^2}(x) - 7x} \right)^2} = 7x + \sqrt {7x} 
\end{array}

Now I'm doing calculus using chain rule:

\begin{array}{l}
2\left( {{f^2}(x) - 7x} \right)\left( {2f(x)f'(x) - 7} \right) = 7\left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {7x} }}} \right)\\
\sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } \left( {2f(x)f'(x) - 7} \right) = \frac{7}{2}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {7x} }}} \right)\\
2f(x)f'(x) = \frac{7}{2}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } }}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {7x} }}} \right) + 7\\
2f(x)f'(x) = 7\left( {\frac{1}{{2\sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } }}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {7x} }}} \right) + 1} \right)\\
f(x)f'(x) = \frac{7}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{{2\sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } }}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {7x} }}} \right) + 1} \right)
\end{array}

No needs to factor it out:
\begin{array}{l}
f'(x) = \frac{7}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{{2\sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } }}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {7x} }}} \right) + 1} \right)\frac{1}{{f(x)}}\\
f'(x) = \frac{7}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{{2\sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } }}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {7x} }}} \right) + 1} \right)\frac{1}{{\sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } } }}
\end{array}

But if somebody wanted to:

$$f'(x) = \left( {\frac{{14\sqrt x  + \sqrt 7 }}{{8\sqrt {7{x^2} + x\sqrt {7x} } }} + \frac{7}{2}} \right)\frac{1}{{\sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x + \sqrt {7x} } } }}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{d\left( \sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}\right) }{dx}\\
=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}\dfrac{d\left( 7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}\right) }{dx}\\
=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}\left ( 7+\dfrac{d\left(\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}\right) }{dx}\right)\\
=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}\left ( 7+\left (\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}\dfrac{d\left(7x+\sqrt{7x}\right) }{dx}\right)\right)\\
=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}\left ( 7+\left (\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}\left(7+\dfrac{d\left(\sqrt{7x}\right) }{dx}\right)\right)\right)\\
=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}\left ( 7+\left (\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}\left(7+\left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x}}\dfrac{d\left(7x\right) }{dx}\right)\right)\right)\right)\\
=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}}\left ( 7+\left (\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7x+\sqrt{7x}}}\left(7+\left(\dfrac{7}{2\sqrt{7x}}\right)\right)\right)\right)=\dots$$